# Microsoft Playerframework variable source

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a Windows Store App with a music stream inside it. For playing the stream, I'm using the Microsoft Playerframework for XAML.

Listining to one stream is no problem, but I want to use multiple streams, randomly choosed by my C# code.

The problem is, I can't put a variable in the source definition from the media player.

XAML:

```
<mmppf:MediaPlayer Source="http://linktostream"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a page to serve up the random stream? e.g:

```
"http://linktostream/StreamPage.aspx?stream=Random"
```

serving the stream through that page?

I haven't used the framework so obviously I could be wrong.

Comment: No I can't. We have a weatherstation linked with the App, and the weather make the choise for the stream. So if it's 30°c, and the wind is from the west of the Netherlands, we want a radio stream from somewhere in America. We have streams, and the code to write te if/else of Switch is no problem to write. But we can't put the "decision" into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mmppf:MediaPlayer Name="myMediaPlayer" />
```

In the c# code:

```
         ...
         myMediaPlayer.Source = GetRandomSource();
    }

    private Uri GetRandomSource()
    {
        // Get an uri randomly
    }
```